# How to proxy rest api calls with correct headers in Apache as it comes from that server?

Tags: apache, rest, proxy, httpd.conf

How can I correctly proxy rest api call through another server as if it comes from that server ?

Developers need to talk a a remote rest api on domain sub.xyz.com that is only accessible through domain xyz.com (Access-Control-Allow-Origin). So I though of setting up a http proxy on the server that host domain xyz.com as if the calls come from that domain.
However, I do get the following error:

> 403 Forbidden
>   Access was denied to this resource.
>   Unauthorized: get_collection failed permission check

The apache httpd config I use:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass /api https://sub.xyz.com/api
ProxyPassReverse /api https://sub.xyz.com/api
```

How do I set this up correctly such that it works?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the front end server name preserved when reaching the backend you should set:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

You should probably additionally add:

```
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
```

and/or

```
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
```

Or the connection will fail in ssl handshake due to contacting the backend with a host name which does not match its certificate CN.

---

Based on your comments if you want to make the backend also think the proxy is making the requests, maybe you should start removing proxy headers like:

```
ProxyAddHeaders off
```

But it really depends on what the backend looks at to determine who is accessing it.

Comment: No, the api should see the request as if it's made by the proxy server. How to realize this?

Comment: @edbras I modified the answer based on your comments.

Comment: Thanks, just added ProxyAddHeaders but it keeps giving the same error. I am not sure how to see why ?

Comment: @edbras you will have to check the backend to see what exactly is being checked